# htaccess - redirect to exact folder with different rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess that makes pretty url. The content is like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(en|ru)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&section=$2 [QSA,L]
```

but I also have a folder - /ru/forum and I need my htaccess to have an exception for this url to parse /ru/forum/index.php . How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(en|ru)/((?!forum/)[a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&section=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: awesome. Didn't think of simply adding an exception :) worked like a charm. thanks a lot